# 404 error when I test order-update - Transactions API in Actions on Google

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to test API transaction node with Google DialogFlow.
I use [Actions on Google: Transactions Sample github file](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs).
When I type `node order-update.js` (step 8) I see this error:

```
{ error:
   { code: 404,
     message: 'Requested entity was not found.',
     status: 'NOT_FOUND' } }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I opened an issue in the github project, however, I am still not able to solve the problem. Have you fixed it already?